# VIM(Mercurial) +python3.2 on debian wheezy: Could not load library function PySys_SetArgv

Tags: python, vim

```
> ./configure --enable-python3interp=dynamic --enable-gui=gtk2
> --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.2/

make

vim --version|grep pyth

    +cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +viminfo
    -cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +vreplace
```

but if i do: :python3 print('hi')
I get:

```
E448: Could not load library function PySys_SetArgv
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing the trailing '/' in this line *'--with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.2/'*

like so: **--with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.2**